# I want to search for data when I select multi-user and multi-project using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to search for data when I select multi-user and multi-project then I click on the search button but unfortunately, data is not showing on the report.

**return $request**

```
   {
   "_token": 
  "Y293JntHDWb40vqe5hG80ebhoxsxAGaWA00DcAkn",
   "user": [
    "3",
    "4",
   "8"
   "project": [
   "43",
   "44",
   "45",
   "46"
   ],
   "date": "2001-01-20 - 2020-07-02"
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public function search(Request $request)
{
    //  return $request;
    $date = explode(' - ', $request->date);
    $auth = Auth::user();
    $hourLog = Hourlog::with('project', 
    'user');
    if ($request->user) {
    foreach ($request->user  as  $users) {

    $hourLog->where("user_id", $users);
    }
    } else if ($auth->user_type == 1) {
      $hourLog->where("user_id", $auth->id);
    }
    if ($request->project) {
    foreach ($request->project  as  $projects) 
   {
    $hourLog->where("project_id", $projects);
    }
    }
    $data = [
    "hourlogs"  => $hourLog- 
     >whereBetween('date', $date)
    ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
     ->orderBy('start_time', 'asc')
     ->get(),
      "date"      => $date,
    ];
    return view('cms.reports.report-list', 
    $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well the problem seems to be with your query at the point where you add `$hourLog->where("user_id", $request->user);` because this adds the conditions for each user separately with an `and` between them. How about trying a `whereIn('user_id', $users)`?
The same goes for project_id-s.